# AWS DMS Replicate from MSSQL Cloud DB to On-premise MSSQL DB

Tags: aws-dms

As part of our DR plan, we'd like to setup AWS DMS service with MSSQL 2019 SE RDS Cloud DB as source and MSSQL 2012 SE On-premise DB instance as our target to replicate changes from RDS MSSQL 2019 DB(Source) to On-premise MSSQL2012 DB(Target) instance(Task migration type: Replicate data changes only). Though we could not see any DMS limitations that restrict replicating from a higher MSSQL version to a lower version, running the pre-migration test not highlighting this compatibility issues, receiving an error "SQL_ERROR SqlState: 24000 NativeError: 0 Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid cursor state; Failed while preparing stream component".

The question here is, it would be helpful to know whether anyone tried this similar use case or is aware of any limitation that restricts replication from RDS MSSQL 2019 DB to On-premise MSSQL2012 DB instance, please. Thanks in advance.